# Multiple joins with two association tables in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, join, sqlalchemy

I've this (simplified, but working) piece of code to handle the concept of workspaces, where every workspace can have members (users assigned to a workspace) and teams (also belonging to workspaces).

```py
import json

from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Boolean, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref


db_uri = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1/test_db"

db = create_engine(db_uri)  
Base = declarative_base()


class UserWorkspaceRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_workspace_role"
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    workspace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('workspace.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
    

class UserWorkspaceTeam(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_workspace_team"
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    workspace_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('workspace.id'), primary_key=True)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('team.id'), primary_key=True)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    team_workspaces = relationship(UserWorkspaceTeam, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="user")
    role_workspaces = relationship(UserWorkspaceRole, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="user")


class Workspace(Base):
    __tablename__ = "workspace"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    team_users = relationship(UserWorkspaceRole, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="workspace")
    role_users = relationship(UserWorkspaceTeam, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="workspace")


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = "role"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    role = relationship(UserWorkspaceRole, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="role")


class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = "team"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String)
    team = relationship(UserWorkspaceTeam, cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="team")


Session = sessionmaker(db)  
session = Session()

Base.metadata.create_all(db)
#Base.metadata.drop_all(db)

# Add roles
role_owner = Role(name="owner")
role_member = Role(name="member")
roles = [role_owner, role_member]
session.add_all(roles)
session.commit()

# Add teams
team_1 = Team(name="Team_1")
team_2 = Team(name="Team_2")
teams = [team_1, team_2]
session.add_all(teams)
session.commit()

# Add users
user1 = User(name="User_1")
user2 = User(name="User_2")
user3 = User(name="User_3")
users = [user1, user2, user3]
session.add_all(users)
session.commit()


workspace1 = Workspace(name="Apple")

test1 = UserWorkspaceRole(user=user1,workspace=workspace1, role_id="1")
test2 = UserWorkspaceRole(user=user2,workspace=workspace1, role_id="2")
test3 = UserWorkspaceRole(user=user3,workspace=workspace1, role_id="2")
test4 = UserWorkspaceTeam(user=user1,workspace=workspace1, team_id="1")
test5 = UserWorkspaceTeam(user=user1,workspace=workspace1, team_id="2")

records = [test1, test2, test3, test4, test5]
session.add_all(records)

session.commit()

x = session.query(UserWorkspaceRole).join(User).join(Workspace).join(Role).filter(Workspace.id == '1').all()

members = []

for n in range(len(x)):
    members.append(
            {
            "workspace": x[n].workspace.id,
            "name": x[n].user.name,
            "role": x[n].role.name
            }
        )
print(json.dumps(members, indent=4))
```

Which gives the following output:

```sh
[
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_1",
        "role": "owner"
    },
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_3",
        "role": "member"
    },
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_2",
        "role": "member"
    }
]
```

What I'd like to achieve is to add to every dictionary in the list, the teams a user belongs to in a certain workspace. Can I achieve this with one query? I tried to join also the UserWorkspaceTeam, but probably I'm missing something (I'm pretty newbie with db stuff).

The output I'd like should look like this:

```sh
[
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_1",
        "role": "owner",
        "teams": [
            {"id": "1", "name": "Team_1"},
            {"id": "2", "name": "Team_2"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_3",
        "role": "member"
    },
    {
        "workspace": 1,
        "name": "User_2",
        "role": "member"
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `range()` function in your `for` loop the upper bound that you specified falls short by one. Try joining the `UserWorkspaceTeam` like you did before but this time add to the upper bound of the range function allowing you to reach the last index. Hopefully this helps.

```
x = session.query(UserWorkspaceRole).join(User).join(Workspace).join(Role).join(UserWorkspaceTeam).filter(Workspace.id == '1').all()

members = []

# The range() function includes values from 0 until a bound you specify but not including it.
for n in range(len(x)+1):
    members.append(
        {
        "workspace": x[n].workspace.id,
        "name": x[n].user.name,
        "role": x[n].role.name,
        }
    )
print(json.dumps(members, indent=4))
```